# How to disable the advertisements when sshing into an Ubuntu machine

Tags: ssh, motd

When sshing into my machine, I see the following:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.6-sound-29 x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

 * Security certifications for Ubuntu!
   We now have FIPS, STIG, CC and a CIS Benchmark.

   - http://bit.ly/Security_Certification

 * Want to make a highly secure kiosk, smart display or touchscreen?
   Here's a step-by-step tutorial for a rainy weekend, or a startup.

   - https://bit.ly/secure-kiosk


 * Canonical Livepatch is available for installation.
   - Reduce system reboots and improve kernel security. Activate at:
     https://ubuntu.com/livepatch

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Last login: Sat Oct 13 18:31:05 2018 from ::1
```

How to disable these advertisements, without disabling the update and login parts (the *Want to make a highly secure kiosk, smart display or touchscreen? ...* part)?

Comment: Identify the content of the files in your directory `/etc/update-motd.d` and modify or remove the content that creates the advertisements that you want to get rid of.

Comment: Just go to `/etc/update-motd.d` and execute (or examine) the scripts there one by one. For the ones you don't like do `chmod -x $script` to disable their execution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When logging into a computer with SSH, a lot of text is displayed before reaching the command prompt. This comes from the **motd** (message of the day) process. The text can be somewhat overwhelming in volume.

To reduce or mostly eliminate this text, edit `/etc/default/motd-news` and change `ENABLED=1` to `ENABLED=0`.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 18.04+, this can be done by removing the execute bits from unwanted scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d`.